# upgrade controller to SATA 3

Tags: hard-drive, sata

my laptop (Dell 5537) has one SATA-3 connection and a SATA-2 DVD reader/writer. I've removed the DVD and placed an extra HDD in its place. So now I have a SSD in SATA-3 port and a HDD in SATA-2 DVD port (using an adapter of course). Is there any chance to upgrade the SATA-2 to SATA-3 because I'm thinking of getting another SSD instead of the HDD?

This is [SANDRA report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo7gw.png)

Comment: How do you figure out that the originally-DVD port is SATA is only capable of 3Gb/s?

Comment: Sandra 'said' so... The SSD port is capable of 6Gb/s while the DVD port is only capable of 3Gb/s...

Comment: http://www.dell.com/us/dfh/p/inspiron-15r-5537/pd#TechSpec http://ark.intel.com/products/64345/Intel-BD82HM76-PCH The chipset should support 6.0Gb/s on up to two ports though. (Btw being capped at 3.0Gb/s doesn't mean it's SATA 2)

Comment: I think there's one thing you can try: see if there's a option in BIOS/UEFI that is about "external SATA" / "eSATA" / "Hot Plug". If there is, you can try to disable it and see if it changes the available rate. Apparently being set as "external SATA" will make the port being capped at 3.0Gb/s: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/7-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.html

Comment: @Tom Yan: I've uploaded SANDRA report, if it helps. Do you think there's potential for 6Gb/s in the 2nd port? Perhaps it's set to 3Gb/s because the HDD does not actually need more? No BIOS access to such options...

Comment: Well there's definitely potential, since it's clearly stated in the spec of the chipset. If Sandra prints "Port    G2 / SATA300" even when nothing is connected to the port, then it probably has nothing to do with the HDD, but because the port is an "external SATA" port. It's just a matter whether that can be changed in BIOS/UEFI. But if it prints nothing when the HDD is not connected to it, then it might be just telling you the spec of the HDD.

Comment: @Tom Yan: Thanks to your comments, I checked with another SSD as a second drive and SANDRA indicated that I have two SATA-3 ports! Although my HDD is a SATA3 device, the port was working as SATA2. I suppose it has to be an energy-conserving mechanism of the BIOS? Well... I'm happy regardless!

Comment: As I've said, supporting only 3.0Gb/s doesn't mean that the drive is SATA 2; there are also SATA 2 drives that claims to support 6.0Gb/s. The SATA version and the transfer rate a drive supports is indicated by DIFFERENT "words" in its ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE data. The former is indicated by word 222, while the latter is indicated by word 76.

Comment: Same case for the chipset and ports. If the chipset support the FEATURES of SATA 3, then all its port are SATA 3 ports. Whether all the ports is capable of having a 6.0Gb/s speed is ANOTHER matter. For example, the chipset of your laptop used can support 6 ports but allows only up to 2 of them being at 6.0Gb/s rate, but that doesn't make others of them "SATA 2" ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  SATA controller chips are soldered onto laptop motherboards.  You will not be able to replace the SATA controller.  However, even SATA2 at 3Gb/s is very fast.

Attach your SSD to it and you can see firsthand what the speed will be like.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 3Gb/s would cut a fast SSD speed to almost half. I'm currently using a HDD which is fine but a SSD capable of speeds like 500+MB/s would have bottleneck issues with SATA2.